# Comparing two dataframes in Spark using Java?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a table named 'sample_event' which looks like

```
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+
| id  | log_timestamp           | action_performed  | activity_date |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+
| 1   |  2017-06-01 23:40:07.0  | Clicked           | 2017-06-01    |
+-----+-------------------------+-------------------+---------------+
```

The schema of this table with datatypes :-

```
 root
  |-- id: integer (nullable = true)
  |-- log_timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)
  |-- action_performed: string (nullable = true)
  |-- activity_date: date (nullable = true)
```

I get my dataframe like

```
Dataset<Row> df = sparkContext.sql("SELECT * FROM sample_event WHERE id=1")
```

I want to test the values and type of data frame by creating a new data frame with the same values from table. How can I create a data frame in Java with above schema ?

Comment: Not able to understand what do you mean by "I want to test the values and type of data frame by creating a new data frame with the same values from table" , Do you want to create one more dataframe with the same values ?

Comment: @AvishekBhattacharya Yes, want to create a data frame with same values.

Comment: Create copy of `sample_event` then insert to df from source table based on filter logic- `sqlContext.sql("create table df like sample_event");  `

Answer (score 0):

**Create Table Like**

```
CREATE TABLE [IF NOT EXISTS] [db_name.]table_name1 LIKE [db_name.]table_name2 [LOCATION path]
```

Create a MANAGED table using the definition/metadata of an existing table or view. The created table always uses its own directory in the default warehouse location.